# Using IF statements to avoid adding duplicates with an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to learn about databases and SQL, and this is an issue I'm having trouble with: how do I detect if a new entry is a duplicate, and if it is, not *discard* the new entry, but merge it with the old one?

An example makes it clearer. Let's say that I'm making a database of my video game collection.  My columns are 'Title' (varchar) and then a boolean column for each platform I own the game on, since some games are on multiple platforms.

I buy World of Goo, and go to my database to say

```
INSERT INTO `collections`.`games` (`Title`,`Windows`) VALUES ('World of Goo','1');
```

Easy. But six months later, I buy it again on Android, because I really like that game and want to play it in bed. What I want to do now is write a query that says

```
IF (select * from `games` where title = 'World of Goo') {
    UPDATE `games`
    SET `Android` = '1'
    WHERE `title` = 'World of Goo';
} ELSE {
        INSERT INTO `collections`.`games` (`Title`,`Android`) VALUES ('World of Goo','1'); 
}
```

(I know the first line is wrong, I'd need to write "if query returns 1 or more results", but ignore that for now.)

Now... I know I could do this with a PHP script. But I don't want to use a more complex solution than is necessary -- is there a way do this in SQL alone?

(And this is an example of a problem, I know that in reality I'd remember that I owned a game and just write the query to update it.)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has implemented an *UPSERT* statement using [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
INSERT INTO collections.games (Title, Android) 
VALUES ('World of Goo', '1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Android = '1'
```

but in order to work the statement above, you need to make column `Title` unique.

```
ALTER TABLE games ADD CONSTRAINT games_uq UNIQUE (Title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed by the tags you are using MySQL. My suggestion is to use [INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and have title as primary key (declared as `UNIQUE`):

```
INSERT INTO `collections`.`games` (`Title`,`Windows`) VALUES ('World of Goo','1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Windows`=VALUES(`Windows`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [insert into ... on duplicate key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO  games (Title,Android) VALUES ('World of Goo','1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Android=1
```

Remember that your Title column has tu be UNIQUE. If it is not, let it be with:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_title
ON games (Title)
```

**Anyways, i think your model is not the best**, since if youu consider a new platform in the future, **you will have to alter the table**, and probaly update many records.

I would prefer a games table, a platforms table, and a game_rel_platform table where you put an entry for every gameid-platformid pair